# Julia struct error "no method matching iterate"

Tags: struct, julia

While trying to understand parametric structs in Julia, I defined following struct as a subtype of AbstractSet

```
struct MySet{T} <: AbstractSet{T}
    st::Vector{T}
    MySet(x::Vector{T}) where {T} = new{T}(x)
end
```

However, I get following error when I try to create a new object of type MySet

```
julia> MySet([1,2])

       MethodError: no method matching iterate(::MySet{Int64})
       Closest candidates are:
       iterate(::Union{LinRange, StepRangeLen}) at ~/julia-1.7.1-linux-x86_64/julia- 
       1.7.1/share/julia/base/range.jl:826 
       iterate(::Union{LinRange, StepRangeLen}, ::Integer) at ~/julia-1.7.1-linux- 
       x86_64/julia-1.7.1/share/julia/base/range.jl:826
       iterate(::T) where T<:Union{Base.KeySet{<:Any, <:Dict}, 
       Base.ValueIterator{<:Dict}} at ~/julia-1.7.1-linux-x86_64/julia- 
       1.7.1/share/julia/base/dict.jl:695
```

Can someone help me understand why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 5):

The `MySet` object gets created as you can see here:

```
julia> x = MySet([1,2]);

julia> x.st
2-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
```

The problem is that it is not displayed correctly. The reason is that `AbstractSet` have a custom `show` method that gets called for them which assumes that your `AbstractSet` object is iterable.

What you can do to learn what minimal set of methods you should implement for `AbstractSet` until it gets documented is by writing:

```
julia> subtypes(AbstractSet)
5-element Vector{Any}:
 Base.IdSet
 Base.KeySet
 BitSet
 Set
 Test.GenericSet

julia> using Test

julia> methodswith(GenericSet)
[1] isempty(s::GenericSet) in Test
[2] iterate(s::GenericSet, state...) in Test
[3] length(s::GenericSet) in Test
```

The reason I pick `GenericSet` is that it is documented as:

```
help?> GenericSet
search: GenericSet GenericString GenericDict GenericOrder GenericArray

The GenericSet can be used to test generic set APIs that program to
the AbstractSet interface, in order to ensure that functions can work
with set types besides the standard Set and BitSet types.
```

so what `GenericSet` defines should be the minimum that `AbstractSet` interface requires.

(above I show you the full process you could use to discover what is needed, as guessing that `GenericSet` should be checked is non-obvious without the previous steps)

Comment: Another way to see it (according to [this Hacker news comment](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=27964054) ) is that these error messages are the guide to making your `struct MySet` a proper `AbstractSet`, that follows its expected interface. Julia doesn't have formal interfaces, but these error messages when you try to use your `MySet` as an `AbstractSet` can tell you which parts of the expected interface you are missing.

Comment: To be clear, however, my preference is for Julia to have properly documented interfaces (beyond [just AbstractArrays](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/interfaces/#man-interface-array) ), and maybe we'll get those in the future. The above is just a pragmatic, ugly way of making use of the current behaviour to figure things out.

Comment: 100% agreed. It would be much better that the interfaces would be explicitly defined. I have updated my answer to reflect this.